# mysql select query with joins

Tags: php, mysql

I need some data from database but i am fail to perform query. i am explaing the data base table and then my desired result can anyone help me to perform the right query. I shall b very thankful.

Table - Bill Status

```
bill no    saleman    shop           amount
-------------------------------------------
1          umer       Best Mart      3000
2          umer       E-mart         4000
3          umer       Shopping Club  2000
4          umer       The Store      1000
5          umer       Rachna S/S     1500
```

Table - Ledger

```
bill no    saleman    shop          credit    debit
---------------------------------------------------    
1           umer    Best Mart                  200
2           umer    E-mart          100    
            umer    Royal Store     1000    
            umer    Chenab Store    1800    
            umer    Elite Mart      3500    
            umer    The Mart        5000
```

Desired Result

```
billno    saleman    shop            amount    credit    debit
--------------------------------------------------------------    
1         umer       Best Mart       3000                 200
2         umer       E-mart          4000      100    
3         umer       Shopping Club   2000        
4         umer       The Store       1000        
5         umer       Rachna S/S      1500        
          umer       Royal Store               1000    
          umer       Chenab Store              1800    
          umer       Elite Mart                3500    
          umer       The Mart                  5000
```

Comment: There are one constraint, If saleman have duplicate shop in any of tables. If no then T-I's answer should be what you are looking.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that the relation is based on salesman and shop then try something like

```
SELECT 
    b.bill_no
    , b.saleman
    , b.shop
    , b.amount
    , l.credit
    , l.debit
FROM bill_status b
INNER JOIN ledger l
        ON l.saleman = b.saleman
       AND l.shop = b.shop
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Following.

**Select * from table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1_billno=table2_billno;**

You can use this query to get the data from both table where bill no of both table are same.
You got my Point?

Comment: i want both sides data. with this query it not take last four transaction of table 2

Comment: use should perform join operation on the salesman collumn name.

Comment: Now,Your query sould be look like this.                           Select * from table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1_saleman=table2_saleman;

Answer (score 0):

You are looking of UNION:

```
SELECT *, '' as credit, '' as debit
FROM bill_results

UNION ALL

SELECT *, '' as amount
FROM ledger
```

Make sure the tables has the same columns